# Whatsapp preview doesn't work while Facebook and Twitter does

Tags: gatsby, whatsapp, preview, react-helmet

I've read a lot of SOF question about this, but none of them explain why such thing would happen to my website. The URL is this one: https://www.acaciadaborborema.com.br/ and you can check all meta-tags that come with the HTML.

The rich preview works just fine in Facebook and Twitter but, for some reason, **it doesn't work for Whatsapp**, not even the title + description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution, and it's not something I would've considered initially.

I use Gatsby.js to build my website, thus I have to use something like `react-helmet` to add the meta tags, which works nice (since gatsby has SSR), but the problem is caused by **a relatively big style tag before the meta tags**, with some CSS for the site. And, as it turns out, Whatsapp does care about that.

*edit:* just a `style` tag doesn't mess the Whatsapp Preview, but a big one will  (it was the entire *tachyons* library)

Comment: You forgot to actually state the steps you took to fix the issue.

Comment: Bang on dude! This is exactly what was causing the issue for me. I just had to move the meta tags above the relatively long style tag(s). That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that most services cache the first resolution of a page and use that cached version for very long periods of time. While Facebook provides a way to clear that cache, LinkedIn for example doesn't. That might be the case with WhatsApp too.

Try creating a new page using the same template but provide a new unique url. See if that works in WhatsApp.

Comment: Yes, every time I make a little change I test with another URL.

Facebook and Twitter offer developers a page to invalidate cached preview, by the way.

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `gatsby-ssr.js`

```
export const onPreRenderHTML = ({
  getHeadComponents,
  replaceHeadComponents,
}) => {
  const headComponents = getHeadComponents();
  headComponents.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.type === "meta") {
      return -1;
    } else if (b.type === "meta") {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  replaceHeadComponents(headComponents);
};
```

Source
https://dev.to/lucis/whatsapp-link-preview-is-weird-d0o